# How to retrieve multiple fields in an index of an array in firestore using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the link below, I have some data in firestore.

My Firestore structure :

[image]

I have an array in the appointmentReminderTime field. Each of those indices has MedicationName, notificationType, and time. I have a feature called "View Reminders" where it shows my users all the reminders they have set previously. I want MedicationName, notificationType, and time to be passed as string and the user be able to see their reminders.

Here is some code snippet that i wrote

ViewAppointmentReminders.dart

```
            ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: user.appointmentName.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return appointmentDataitems(user.appointmentName[index],context);
              },
            ),


//List tile for appointment name and then appointment value
Container appointmentDataitems(String appointmentName, BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 40.0,
    child: ListTile(
      leading: Text(
        "Appointment name:",
      ),
      trailing: Text(
        appointmentName,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

user.dart

```
class User 
{
  final List<dynamic> appointmentName;

  User(
      {
      this.appointmentName,
      });
}
```

so in conclusion, using Flutter I want to display the data above dynamically for the users to see their appointment/medication reminders

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your model for appointment of user will be as follows:

```
class User{
  List<Appointment> appointments;
  User({this.appointments});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "appointmentReminderTime": this.appointments
  };


  User.fromJson(Map jsonMap)
      : appointments =   (jsonMap['appointmentReminderTime'] as List)
      ?.map((i) => Appointment.fromJson(i))
      ?.toList();

}

class Appointment {
  final String medicationName;
  final String notificationType;
  final Timestamp time;

  const Appointment(this.medicationName, this.notificationType,this.time);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "MedicationName": this.medicationName,
    "notificationtype": this.notificationType,
    "time": this.time
  };

  Appointment.fromJson(Map jsonMap)
      : medicationName = jsonMap['MedicationName'],
        notificationType = jsonMap['notificationtype'],
        time = jsonMap['time'];
}
```

You will fetch data from firestore with type **User** and then this is how you will show them in UI.

```
ListView.builder(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
           itemCount: user.appointments.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                   return appointmentDataitems(user.appointments[index],context);
                    },
      ),


//List tile for appointment name and then appointment value
Container appointmentDataitems(Appointment appointment, BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 40.0,
    child: ListTile(
      leading: Text(
        appointment.medicationName,
      ),
      trailing: Text(
        appointment.notificationType,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, this would work if i didnt have anything else in my user class. I have other objects that im defining in the user class and having appointments be the only ones with a jsonMap gives me an error telling me that other objects are not initialized by that User.fromJson constructor. How do i go about that fixing that?

Comment: Rename this User class to UserData and then create another class named User and in it declare final User user; In this way you can have other objects too in the User class.